# Android gcm client using GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the new way of using gcm described [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) using `GoogleCloudMessaging` class.
But 9 out of 10 times it is giving me `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error. Only once it registers a device.

```
07-01 14:24:55.907    2074-2090/com.deveyes.carrefour          W/System.err:                   java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

07-01 14:24:56.037    2074-2090/com.deveyes.carrefour          W/System.err: at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
```

My code is as follows inside my Activity:

```
 .....
     gcmRegId = gcm.register(CarrefourConfig.GCM_SENDER_ID);   
 .....
```

Later I came to know that I need to use Automatic retry. I have read [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html) but this document seems to be old. As with the new way we do not use IntentService anymore. or do we ? Inside BroadcastReciever i can get the message and notify user.

what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT:

MY manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<supports-screens
        android:xlargeScreens="false"
 />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />

<permission
        android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour.android.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<permission android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Carrefour"
        android:name=".CarrefourApplication">

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCKznwauzk_rNdKf7Qw0rjpmf4AWchCRwI" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver
            android:name=".gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--service android:name=".services.CarrefourLocationService" /-->


</application>
```

My MainActivity:

```
private void registerBackground() {

    new AsyncTask(){

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            try {
                if(gcm == null){
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                 gcmRegId = gcm.register(CarrefourConfig.GCM_SENDER_ID);

                Log.i(TAG,"regid:"+gcmRegId);

                setRegistrationId(context,gcmRegId);
                ServerUtilities.register(context,gcmRegId);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(null,null,null);
}
```

Comment: Please include more code (your manifest + the method in which you call `gcm.register`). If you call `gcm.register` in the main thread, it's a bug.

Comment: pls check ur sender id

Comment: added code, my sender d is correct. sometimes it registers the device,sometimes not.

Comment: hey Shahriar, did you figure out what the issue was ? i am struggling with the same currently.

Comment: @victorn., not really! For the time being I pulled back to the old api as I needed to release a beta version ASAP. Still looking into it :(

Comment: ok thanks : ) i believe i will just do the same.

Comment: @Shahriar, hey i was able to fix the bug on my side. it was my fault. for some reason my AsyncTask was being cancelled while registration was in progress. i looked at the code for GoogleCloudMessaging. they wrap a InterruptedException in an IOException which makes the whole thing confusing. again the issue is with async tasks being cancelled, nothing to do with GCM servers...

Comment: @victorn. , ok, I will have a deeper look into it. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem :

You should use the same package name in all 3 places below, but you use `com.deveyes.carrefour.android` in some cases and `com.deveyes.carrefour` in other cases.

```
<permission android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
...
    <receiver
            android:name=".gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

If your package name is `com.deveyes.carrefour`, change the manifest to :

```
<permission android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
...
    <receiver
            android:name=".gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.deveyes.carrefour" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: thanks for correcting the mistake. But still the SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE is showing. it works 1-2 times, fails for the rest of the times. A Server issue in the google side ?

Comment: @Shahriar I thought it would solve your problem. I had a similar problem when I put a wrong package name in the permissions part of the manifest. The registration would fail in most cases. The problem went away when I found the error in the manifest and fixed it.

Comment: Aside from ensuring above packages are all the same, if you are using gradle, make sure applicationId is also the same in build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

hey in the GCM jar there should be something called GCMRegistrar you should use that method to register to GCM. following is the code, try it

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
 GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
             GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); //this is where it registers
        } else {

            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

i hope it works for you

Comment: That's the old (now deprecated) API. The OP wanted to register to GCM using the new `GoogleCloudMessaging` class.

Comment: what should I use now ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati hi Raju you could use the new Googlecloudmessaging API try to use this link http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html and this one too http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html if you still can't do it send me an email at dharma.1211[at]gmail[dot]com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

9/20 throws the SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE exception. Apparently it is a bug in the Google's side. Works on some devices (S3) and does not on others (LG L5).

Check [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=57699&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=57699#makechanges).

I think the thing to do is use the old API temporarily until the issue is resolved.